# Autowire a Bean from dependent library jar

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a `Spring Boot application` (`main-app`) which users Library jar `client-app.jar` and mentioned as a dependency in of the application `main-app`.

Now I want to use `@Autowire` to inject bean from `client-app`. For this i have to add `@ComponentScan` on my `main-app` application.

But is there a way that i don't have to anything on my `main-app` by changing code on `client-app`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a `sub-package` by following the `main-app` let's say `main-app` has the following root of package `com.example.main-app` then on your `client-app` you should create something like `com.example.main-app.client-app` then the main application will scan its base package and will look the `client-app` as well.